# How to call a function in views file which is defined in view model file - jQuery

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have this below qQuery fuction which is setting few objects to null.

```
$.fn.myfunction = function() { 
var newAppointmentDetails = {
    AppointmentStatusTypeId: null,
    AppointmentStatusId: null,
    AppointmentType: null,
    CallDate: null,
```

};
    }`

I call this function 'myfunction' from my view file (separate file) and I get object undefined error.

```
fn.myfunction();
```

How do I call this function ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare it like so:

```
var myFunction = function(){ var newAppointments = ... };
```

You may then call it directly:

```
myFunction()
```